# Java @AssociationOverride in one entity messes it in another entity

Tags: java, jpa, java-ee-7

I have the following entities:

Offer:

```
@Entity
public class Offer implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Embedded
    @AssociationOverride(name = "fees",
            joinTable = @JoinTable(
                    name = "offer_fees",
                    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "fee_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
                    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "offer_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
            )
    )
    private Quote quote;
```

Quote:

```
@Embeddable
public class Quote implements Serializable {

    @Column(precision = 13, scale = 3)
    private BigDecimal price;
    @OneToMany
    private List<Fee> fees = new ArrayList<>();
```

Fee:

```
@Entity
public class Fee implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @NotNull
    @Column(precision = 8, scale = 4)
    private BigDecimal rate;
```

Each class has the default getters and setters. At this point everything works fine. But then I need to add another entity:

```
@Entity
public class Purchase implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @ManyToOne
    private Offer offer;
    @Embedded
    @AssociationOverride(name = "fees",
        joinTable = @JoinTable(
                name = "purchase_fees",
                inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "fee_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
                joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "purchase_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
        )
    )
    private Quote quote;
```

At this point, my queries stop working. For example, this query:

```
public List<Purchase> getPurchases(BigDecimal price) {
    TypedQuery<Purchase> q = em.createQuery(
            "SELECT p FROM Purchase p"
            + " WHERE p.offer.quote.price = :price", Purchase.class);
    q.setParameter("price", price);

    return q.getResultList();
}
```

Returns this error:

```
org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "id" does not exist Posição: 8 Error Code: 0 Call: SELECT ID, PRICE FROM OFFER WHERE (ID = ?) bind => [1 parameter bound] Query: ReadObjectQuery(referenceClass=Offer sql="SELECT ID, PRICE FROM OFFER WHERE (ID = ?)")
```

I set `drop-and-create` in `persistence.xml` to see if I could find what is wrong:

```
        <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
```

And it is generatting the Offer table without an ID, and offer_fees is not referencing Offer either, but Purchase:

```
ALTER TABLE PURCHASE DROP CONSTRAINT FK_PURCHASE_OFFER_ID
ALTER TABLE offer_fees DROP CONSTRAINT FK_offer_fees_offer_id
ALTER TABLE offer_fees DROP CONSTRAINT FK_offer_fees_fee_id
ALTER TABLE purchase_fees DROP CONSTRAINT FK_purchase_fees_fee_id
SELECT 1
ALTER TABLE purchase_fees DROP CONSTRAINT FK_purchase_fees_purchase_id
SELECT 1
DROP TABLE OFFER CASCADE
DROP TABLE FEE CASCADE
DROP TABLE PURCHASE CASCADE
DROP TABLE offer_fees CASCADE
DROP TABLE purchase_fees CASCADE
CREATE TABLE OFFER (PRICE DECIMAL(13,3))
CREATE TABLE FEE (ID  SERIAL NOT NULL, RATE DECIMAL(8,4), PRIMARY KEY (ID))
CREATE TABLE PURCHASE (ID  SERIAL NOT NULL, PRICE DECIMAL(13,3), OFFER_ID BIGINT, PRIMARY KEY (ID))
CREATE TABLE offer_fees (offer_id BIGINT NOT NULL, fee_id BIGINT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (offer_id, fee_id))
CREATE TABLE purchase_fees (purchase_id BIGINT NOT NULL, fee_id BIGINT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (purchase_id, fee_id))
ALTER TABLE PURCHASE ADD CONSTRAINT FK_PURCHASE_OFFER_ID FOREIGN KEY (OFFER_ID) REFERENCES PURCHASE (ID)
ALTER TABLE offer_fees ADD CONSTRAINT FK_offer_fees_offer_id FOREIGN KEY (offer_id) REFERENCES PURCHASE (ID)
ALTER TABLE offer_fees ADD CONSTRAINT FK_offer_fees_fee_id FOREIGN KEY (fee_id) REFERENCES FEE (ID)
ALTER TABLE purchase_fees ADD CONSTRAINT FK_purchase_fees_fee_id FOREIGN KEY (fee_id) REFERENCES FEE (ID)
ALTER TABLE purchase_fees ADD CONSTRAINT FK_purchase_fees_purchase_id FOREIGN KEY (purchase_id) REFERENCES PURCHASE (ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be related with the schema generation, something related with Hibernate HBM.

I recreated your model of classes, and Liquibase generates the right schema for it:

```xml
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog" xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.5.xsd">
    <changeSet author="(generated)" id="1">
        <createTable tableName="fee">
            <column autoIncrement="true" name="id" type="BIGINT">
                <constraints primaryKey="true" primaryKeyName="feePK"/>
            </column>
            <column name="rate" type="DECIMAL(8, 4)"/>
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>
    <changeSet author="(generated)" id="2">
        <createTable tableName="offer">
            <column autoIncrement="true" name="id" type="BIGINT">
                <constraints primaryKey="true" primaryKeyName="offerPK"/>
            </column>
            <column name="price" type="DECIMAL(13, 3)"/>
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>
    <changeSet author="(generated)" id="3">
        <createTable tableName="offer_fees">
            <column name="offer_id" type="BIGINT">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="fee_id" type="BIGINT">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>
    <changeSet author="(generated)" id="4">
        <createTable tableName="purchase">
            <column autoIncrement="true" name="id" type="BIGINT">
                <constraints primaryKey="true" primaryKeyName="purchasePK"/>
            </column>
            <column name="price" type="DECIMAL(13, 3)"/>
            <column name="offer_id" type="BIGINT"/>
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>
    <changeSet author="(generated)" id="5">
        <createTable tableName="purchase_fees">
            <column name="purchase_id" type="BIGINT">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="fee_id" type="BIGINT">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>
    <changeSet author="(generated)" id="6">
        <addUniqueConstraint columnNames="fee_id" constraintName="UK_efbjp6b9dix0fvvu4ho4c23mx" tableName="offer_fees"/>
    </changeSet>
    <changeSet author="(generated)" id="7">
        <addUniqueConstraint columnNames="fee_id" constraintName="UK_l71j0m0qba02a1sd38km2c7rv" tableName="purchase_fees"/>
    </changeSet>
    <changeSet author="(generated)" id="8">
        <addForeignKeyConstraint baseColumnNames="offer_id" baseTableName="purchase" constraintName="FK8b5b4vp8smfuvge8vgx767b43" deferrable="false" initiallyDeferred="false" referencedColumnNames="id" referencedTableName="offer"/>
    </changeSet>
    <changeSet author="(generated)" id="9">
        <addForeignKeyConstraint baseColumnNames="purchase_id" baseTableName="purchase_fees" constraintName="FKjuwhxm0r6adifk562cy0wlgbv" deferrable="false" initiallyDeferred="false" referencedColumnNames="id" referencedTableName="purchase"/>
    </changeSet>
    <changeSet author="(generated)" id="10">
        <addForeignKeyConstraint baseColumnNames="fee_id" baseTableName="purchase_fees" constraintName="FKkmwtut3mhe5so6bhd55wslxja" deferrable="false" initiallyDeferred="false" referencedColumnNames="id" referencedTableName="fee"/>
    </changeSet>
    <changeSet author="(generated)" id="11">
        <addForeignKeyConstraint baseColumnNames="fee_id" baseTableName="offer_fees" constraintName="FKkp6c8xhv4mrqwbfwpcy5domyv" deferrable="false" initiallyDeferred="false" referencedColumnNames="id" referencedTableName="fee"/>
    </changeSet>
    <changeSet author="(generated)" id="12">
        <addForeignKeyConstraint baseColumnNames="offer_id" baseTableName="offer_fees" constraintName="FKmnqv7yujs8d1mddhtvmrn9cp" deferrable="false" initiallyDeferred="false" referencedColumnNames="id" referencedTableName="offer"/>
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

Please, create manually your schema or use another tool for that task, and see if your model works at runtime properly.

Comment: No, it didn't work. Same error, same wrong table generation (Offer table is generated without id)

Comment: @Heitor I updated my previous answer. I made some test with your model. I think the problem could be related with Hibernate schema generation. Please, create manually your schema or use another tool for that task, and see if your model works at runtime properly.

Comment: Sorry if my reply wasn't clear. I saw that it generated the wrong table, then went and created the correct tables myself. Yet when I run the server, the same error happens (org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "id" does not exist etc...)